# Hack C, Call scripting func instead of C func?

Tags: c, scripting, tuples

The situation is a bit strange but bear with me. I need a scripting language that can easily be called in C (not cpp, C). preferably the script function can be called as a regular C function. I need the scripting language to use tuple's so i can write something like the below. Keep in mine its nonsense, i just want to be able to return tuple. The return type must be a ptr and all inputs are either void* (tuple), int or char*

```
myfunc(a, b, c, d) {
    a.b = b
    a.z = anotherFunc(b,c)
    return a, d
}
myfunc2(z) {
    a, d = z
    return d+4, a+1
}
```

Comment: how do you expect the C compiler know about `myfunc()` if it's a scripting function, that is, defined and changeable at run time?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Lua](http://www.lua.org/), particularly the [API for calling from C](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#3). You should be able to do what you need with it.

Answer (score 0):

[Python](http://www.python.org) can be embedded.  See [Embedding Python in Another Application](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html).

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/). It's [made for calling from C](http://www.ruby-doc.org/doxygen/current/group__ruby__interp.html) (as it's written in C), and the interface is extremely easy. Plus, you get a really powerful language attached to it -- unlike Lua.

As a bonus, it closely matches your specified function-calling interface:

> The return type must be a ptr and all inputs are either void* (tuple), int or char*

Which is pretty much exactly what Ruby's function-calling interface supports.